# Please make the red dot visible also if there are pending reviews near timeout

Tags: feature-request, review, top-bar

([example](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4478))

Now the problem is that surely enough people has seem that site with the privilege of making a decision about my suggestion.

The problem is that the review queues on smaller sites (particularly on smaller betas) are typically zero or very low. Thus, most visitors simply gave up the habit of regularly checking them.

The result is that most review decisions take a looong time. There is not too much to do, and also there are not too much enough well privileged users to vote. But their relation leads to timeouting, or very long-standing reviews, as in the overloaded queues of the largest sites.

The problem could be solved easily, if not only the size of the pending review queue, but also the existence of old, undecided items would trigger the appearance of the red dot.

This is what I am asking for.

<sub>A possible secondary effect would be an increased activity of the high-rep users, i.e. the sites would look more "living".</sub>